# Send RabbitMQ messages to Websocket using Apache Camel

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, rabbitmq, apache-camel

As described in the title I would like to send messages to a Websocket using RabbitMQ. Using AngularJS frontend I want to read the RabbitMQ messages from the Websocket and print them to the console.
In principle my code seems the work, though I can't figure out how to get the actual (string) content of my messages?

**Backend:**
To create the Websocket and do the routing i am using Spring Boot and Apache Camel: http://camel.apache.org/spring-boot.html.

Routing with Camel is easy and my complete Java Code looks like this:

```
@Component
public final class CamelRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public final void configure() throws Exception {
        from("rabbitmq:localhost/myExchange")
                .to("websocket://myEndpoint?sendToAll=true");
    }
}
```

Running the SpringBoot application works without errors and the logs look good:

```
Route: route1 started and consuming from: rabbitmq://localhost/myExchange
```

**RabbitMQ:**
RabbitMQ runs on my localhost. When I go to http://localhost:15672/ I can see that SpringBoot created the *myExchange* and I can send messages to it using *Publish Message* in the UI.
For instance I specify "HelloWorld!" as Payload (without any headers etc.) and click on send.

**Frontend:**
To read messages from the websocket I basically do the following in my AngularJS controller:

```
var socket = {
            start: function () {
                var location = "ws://localhost:9292/myEndpoint";
                this._ws = new WebSocket(location);
                this._ws.onmessage = this._onmessage;
                this._ws.onclose = this._onclose;
            },

            _onmessage: function (m) {
                //Log received RabbitMQ messages from the Websocket
                console.log(m);
            },

            _onclose: function (m) {
                if (this._ws) {
                    this._ws.close();
                }
            }
        };
```

Receiving the messages seems to work in principle.
When I go to my webpage (localhost:8080/) and open the console in Chrome, it prints a "MessageEvent" object with many properties.
None of these properties though seem tocontain the actual message string, i.e.: "HelloWorld!"?

[image]

**Update**:
Instead of using RabbitMQ to deliver messages, I tried doing the same with Apache Kafka instead, and it worked. Here is what I did:

To test I simply setup a Topic called "test" on a local Kafka Broker using a [docker-image](https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka/).
My route config now looks like this:

```
from("kafka:localhost:9092?topic=test&groupId=camelgroupid&autoOffsetReset=earliest&consumersCount=1")
            .to("websocket://dashboard?sendToAll=true");
```

To send messages I use the official [kafka clients library](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.kafka%7Ckafka-clients%7C1.0.0%7Cjar).
Using the same JS code as posted above, I can now see the messages in the MessageObject.data.

I still wonder why the same approach doesn't work with RabbitMQ? Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Add a log statement to log the body after your from() to see what is actually being "get" from your rabbitmq endpoint.

Comment: Like you proposed I added a logger component like this: ".to("log:org.apache.camel.example?level=INFO")"

When I send messages to the queue I receive this log:
org.apache.camel.example                 : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: byte[], Body: HelloWorld].

Hence, the body of the messages is correctly transmitted. Unfortunately it still does not show up in the Websocket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved my problem.

The problem was at the client-side. RabbitMQ sends messages via byte[]. The byte[] needs to be decoded correctly when reading the the message from the Websocket.

Here is my updated and working client code:

```
     var socket = {
        start: function () {
            var location = "ws://localhost:9292/myEndpoint";
            this._ws = new WebSocket(location);
            // RabbitMQ transmits a byte[], therefore we need to change the binary type:
            this._ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
            this._ws.onmessage = this._onmessage;
            this._ws.onclose = this._onclose;
        },

        _onmessage: function (m) {
            // Decode the byte[]:
            var messageString = new TextDecoder('UTF-8').decode(m.data);
            console.log(messageString);
        },

        _onclose: function (m) {
            if (this._ws) {
                this._ws.close();
            }
        }
    };
```